# Getting Bitcoin's block number in a specific date and hour?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, bitcoind, cryptocurrency, bitcoinj

I would like to know what is the Bitcoin block number in an existing date at an exact hour. for example what is the block number closest to 1.1.2017 at 00:00 UTC. What is the easiest way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the time to seconds since the UNIX epoch:

> $ date -ud "1/1/2017"
>   Sun Jan  1 00:00:00 UTC 2017
>   $ date -ud "1/1/2017" +%s
>   1483228800

You can also use [Epoch Converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/) to convert it.

Add three zeroes to that number and append it to a blockchain.com URL:

https://www.blockchain.com/btc/blocks/1483228800000

And there you have it:

> 446033 (Main Chain)   2017-01-01 00:02:33

And if you want the previous block, clock on the previous button and scroll to the end:

> 446032 (Main Chain)   2016-12-31 23:44:04

So block 446,032 was mined at 12/31/2016 at 23:44:04 UTC and block 446,033 was mined at two minutes and 33 seconds after midnight.

Comment: Just a note that the currently working URL is https://blockchain.info/blocks/1483228800000?format=json